# C++ Loop within Switch Case statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How do I loop this switch case? I need to be able to loop back to the menu selection after after each switch case to make a new selection. Help?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

    char choice;
    showWelcome();  // Show Welcom Screen
    showMenu();     // Show Menu Screen
    cin >> choice;  // Make Menu Secection
    {
            switch(choice)
            {
            case'1':
                seriesCalc();
                break;

            case'2':
                parallelCalc();
                break;

            case'q':
                system("cls");
                break;

            default:
                break;
                return 0;
            }

    }       

} // end main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a while loop or a do-while loop. You may want to add the possibility for exit in the switch statement, i.e. `while ( loop ) {` and `case 'q': loop = false`.

This is good because it doesn't automatically quit the program afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(cin){ 
    cin >> choice;  // Make Menu Secection
    {
            switch(choice)
            {
            case'1':
                seriesCalc();
                break;

            case'2':
                parallelCalc();
                break;

            case'q':
                system("cls");
                break;

            default:
                break;
                return 0;
            }

    }       
}
```

Also if you do not mind the `goto` statement:

```
back: cin >> choice;  // Make Menu Secection
{
switch(choice)
{
case'1':
    seriesCalc();
    break;
case'2':
    parallelCalc();
    break;
case'q':
    system("cls");
    break;
default:
    break;
    return 0;
}
goto back;
}
```

However if you plan on going the `goto` way: remember

[image]

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of `goto`.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain There's never an appropriate use of `goto`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Actually, it's useful for error handling in C and embedded programmers pull all kinds of tricks. In C++, probably not ever used legitimately.

Answer (score 0):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

    char choice;boolean again=true;
    showWelcome();  // Show Welcom Screen
    showMenu();   
while(again){  // Show Menu Screen
    cin >> choice;  // Make Menu Secection
    {
            switch(choice)
            {
            case'1':
                seriesCalc();
                break;

            case'2':
                parallelCalc();
                break;

            case'q':
                system("cls");
                break;

            default:
                again=false;
            }

    }  
return 0; 
}    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

```
char choice;
showWelcome();  // Show Welcom Screen
showMenu();     // Show Menu Screen
**while**(cin >> choice)  // Make Menu Secection
{
        switch(choice)
        {
        case'1':
            seriesCalc();
            break;

        case'2':
            parallelCalc();
            break;

        case'q':
            system("cls");
            break;

        default:
            break;
            return 0;
        }

}
```

} // end main

std::cin will return a positive value when the input is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to encapsulate the real work and call it.

```
for(;;) {
    cin >> choice;
    if (!cin || do_user_command(choice) == cmd_exit)
        break;
}
```